# Connect GoPro Hero 7 Black to Macbook Pro 2017 via USB-C

Tags: usb, gopro

I have just bought a Hero 7 Black, which sports a USB-C port. I can use it to charge the battery etc. but I would expect it to also allow me to connect to another device, like my MacBook Pro, with a USB-C port.

I have tried a few configurations:

- a few USB-C to USB-C cables, including one with Thunderbolt 3
- the USB-C to USB-A cable that comes with my GoPro, and the USB-A side goes in an adapter that is then connected via USB-C to my Mac (works with a lot of other devices, so the adapter is fine)

No matter what I do, however, the only thing I succeed in doing is charging the camera.

Do GoPros support a direct USB-C connection to another device?

Answer (score 2):

According to page 61 of the Hero7 Black manual, you can transfer files to your computer using USB-c.  The manual only mentions being able to do this with the Quik application on your computer.  Most likely your computer is missing the drivers necessary to exchange data with the camera due to either not using or not installing this application.

Answer (score 2):

It does work with [GoPro Quik](https://gopro.com/en/us/shop/softwareandapp/quik-%7C-desktop/Quik-Desktop.html) software and I also found that my [Android File Transfer](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/) software picked it up and showed me the SD card as a filesystem I could copy files from just like it would my phone.

Comment: Android File Transfer worked for me on mac OS X Catalina 10.15.2

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to open the GoPro as an external disk.

But you can use the import functions of `Final Cut Pro X`, `iMovie` and the `GoPro Quik` application instead.